# Securing Methods with Spring Security

Tags: java, spring, jsf, spring-security

For our current project, we are integrating JSF and the Spring Framework. I'd like to use Spring Security to handle authentication and authorization. So far, I have implemented a custom `PasswordEncoder` and `AccessDecisionVoter` which are working fine. Now I'm trying to secure methods using the `@Secured` annotation (among others) but I can't get that to work as I would expect it to do.

It seems that the `@Secured` annotation works for bean methods called directly from the JSF layer, only. Here's a simplified example:

```
@Named("foobarBean")
@Scope("access")
public class FoobarBean
{
    @Secured("PERMISSION_TWO")
    public void dummy()
    {
    }

    @Secured("PERMISSION_ONE")
    public String save()
    {
        dummy();
    }
}
```

The method save() is called from the JSF layer like this:

```
<h:commandButton id="save" action="#{foobarBean.save}" />
```

Our `AccessDecisionVoter` is then asked to vote on PERMISSION_ONE but **not** on PERMISSION_TWO. Is this working as designed (I hope not) or am I doing something wrong (what could that be?).

I'd post more code or config but I'm not sure which part is relevant, and I don't want to clutter this post.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is a simple problem of Proxy AOP! If you use Proxy AOP for Security, then the Proxy can only intercept calles that go through the proxy. If one method invoke an other method of the same bean directly, then there is no proxy that can intercept this call. -- And this is the reason why only the the Security Annotation of `save()` is taken in account.

One solution would be using AspectJ AOP instead of Proxy AOP. (It is supported by Spring (Security) too.)

Answer (score 1):

Yes, That is how the `AccessDecisionVoter` works. It takes all roles allowed on a resource(method in your case) and vote for those roles form the current authenticated user's role. If the Role is matched, then only the permission is granted.

In your case also, the only Role defined for the `save` method is `PERMISSION_ONE` so the security system will check against this role only. If logged in user has that role, this method will be executed.

Comment: Ok, I see, and I'm fine with the save() method being called. But save() then calls dummy() which is a secured method, too. I would expect the needed authorities for method dummy() to be checked when it is called by method save()...